# Django's folder structure

Tags: django

I've covered some related topic here on stackoverflow and on some another websites, but still I can't decide, how should I organize Django apps?
Before, I used CodeIgniter and I liked it organization structure.
Ok.
The basic structure looks like

```
testsite/
├── manage.py
│
├── testsite/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
│
└── testapp/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py
```

For example, I need model for users and a blog. Do I need write both of it in -testapp/models.py, or it would be better to create different app for blog / users?

Comment: Well if you are using the User models in different apps, then you should store them in a separate app.

Answer (score 2):

You can put it wherever you think it makes the most sense.  If you are ONLY going to have one Blog model and no functionality related it it, it could make sense to put it inside of your `testapp`, but I'm guessing it will have templates associated with it, url paths, views, so I think it should be its own app `blog`.

The same goes for the `user` model.

Also make sure you check out djangos built in `User` model